# Is there any difference between applying stashed changes, and cherry-picking changes?

Tags: git

I'm wondering if there's any different between the following.

(1)

- `git checkout some-branch`
- (make some local changes)
- `git stash save`
- `git stash pop`

(2)

- `git checkout some-branch`
- (make some local changes)
- `git commit -m "too lazy to write a good message"`; suppose the commit hash is `3282a23d5ddb41328e8a61b4ed5c9faf59af673e`
- `git reset --hard origin/some-branch`
- `git cherry-pick 3282a23d5ddb41328e8a61b4ed5c9faf59af673e`

If so, what are the differences?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused... it looks like you're "moving" the changes to exactly where they already are, are you not?  In the first case, you stash the changes them pop them immediately; that has no net effect that I can think of.  You still have the changes in your work tree and uncommitted.  In the second case, unless your branch was ahead of origin at the beginning of this sequence the cherry-pick just "moves" the changes right to where they already were...  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There may be some small differences inside git repository, since in second case one commit will be created and the `commit` and `reset` operations will move branches forth and back. In contrast, when `git stash` doesn't update branches. In case you wondered, `git stash` adds the contents as a commit (actually, it adds 2 or 3 commit entries, I dont remember exactly).

You should be able to see the differences if you try both out and then check i.e. reflog or some other extended view like:

```
gitk --all $( git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' )
```

In general terms, the net effect for a normal user and normal future use will be just the same: the branch got that new content, and the temporary commit(s) are hidden (not necessarily totally gone yet - as reflog or the command above show).

Answer (score 0):

**First to answer the question in the title:**

Applying stashed changes is something entirely different from cherry-picking commits.

When you apply stashed changes, the changes which are in the stash are applied as uncommitted edited files in you work-tree.

Cherry-picking a commit, is to say that you want to apply the "diff" in one specified commit to the current branch and make a commit. You basically just pick a commit from anywhere and make it the next commit on the current branch. It is for instance useful if you have made some commits on a wrong branch, and you want to pick them to the correct branch later.

**Then explain the difference between the two command sequences:**

There are quite some differences.

```
git checkout some-branch
# (make some local changes)
git stash save
```

is in practice quite the same as:

```
git checkout some-branch
# (make some local changes)
git commit -a -m "My manually stashed away changes"
git reset --hard origin/some-branch
```

In both cases you will end up staying on "some-branch" with none of your new local changes present, but "stashed" away. In the first case, the stashed away changes will be present when you type "git stash list", while in the second case, you will have to run "git reflog" to find the "stashed" away changes.

In your first case (1), you do a "git stash pop" afterwards. It will directly undo the previous line (git stash save). It will add back the stashed away changes to your local working tree, but not add any new commit. The HEAD will still point at the original "some-branch". It will also remove the stash entry from the output of "git stash list".

In your second case (2), you do a "git cherry-pick SHA1" afterwards. This will directly undo the previous command (git reset --hard). You will get back the commit. In order to get the same in case (1), you would have to run

```
git commit -a -m "too lazy to write a good messsage"
```

after "git stash pop"

We could also say that:

```
git checkout some-branch
# (make some local changes)
git stash save
git stash pop
```

is more or less the same as:

```
git checkout some-branch
# (make some local changes)
git commit -a -m "My manually stashed away changes"
git reset origin/some-branch          # without --hard
```

Both basically doing nothing (disregarding that you get "unreachable" commits that you will be able to find in the reflog. Note that unreachable does not mean that you cannot restore them.)